# Widget - unable to load a hot question, check your internet connection

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, android-app-widgets

[image: Widget hot questions]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5X
- OS Version: 7.1.2 (3769476)

I have reinstalled the app, logged in again but the problem remains.

Comment: SE switched to https recently, maybe the app is still try to get data from http address, thus failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.93.

I've also made the Hot Questions widget re-sizable horizontally, so you can have it take up the full width of the screen on bigger devices.